# Opencv Contour can't capture minus and equal to sign

Tags: python, opencv

I am implementing deep learning for a handwritten equation solver. I am using OpenCV contours for capturing digits and mathematical symbols.

[image]

here is my code

```
img = cv2.imread('D:/10-projects/equ1.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
#kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
cv2.imshow("wo",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
img=~img
ret,thresh=cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE )

'''
try: hierarchy = hierarchy[0]
except: hierarchy = []
'''

height, width = img.shape
min_x, min_y = width, height
max_x = max_y = 0
# computes the bounding box for the contour, and draws it on the frame,
cnt=sorted(contours, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
train_data
#for contour, hier in zip(contours, hierarchy):
for contour in cnt:
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    min_x, max_x = min(x, min_x), max(x+w, max_x)
    min_y, max_y = min(y, min_y), max(y+h, max_y)
    if w > 80 and h > 80:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,255,255), 2)
        cv2.imshow('test1',img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        im_crop =thresh[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        im_resize = cv2.resize(im_crop,(28,28))
        cv2.imshow("work",im_resize)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        im_resize=np.reshape(im_resize,(28,28,1))
        train_data.append(im_resize)
```

guide me on how can I capture all digits and symbols. especially - and = signs
if possible you can suggest me other libraries for capturing images like yolo.

Comment: FYI Requesting library recommendations if off-topic on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

I think it happens because of your condition `if w > 80 and h > 80`. The `h` parameter returned by `cv2.boundingRect(contour)` doesn't satisfy the conditon as it is less than 80.

Comment: answer is helpfull but still it is not detection - and =